# how to input two route parameters one of which is in between the URL for navigation while using children routes in Angular CLI 8+ using Angular Router

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular9, angular-router-params

I am trying to navigate to a page providing two route parameters as follows:

`author/journals/:journal_Id/draftArticles/:articleId`

I know that two parameters can be given when route parameter is at the end of the route like `author/journals/draftArticles/:journal_Id/:articleId, journal_Id, articleId` and this will probably solve my issue. But I wanted to maintain the structure I am trying.

```
path: 'author',
        canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
        canActivateChild: [AuthorGuard],
        component: AuthorNavComponent,
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: AuthorDashboardComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full'
          },
          {
            path: 'profile',
            component: AuthorProfileComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full'
          },
          {
            path: 'journals/:journal_Id',
            component: JournalPublicPageComponent,
            pathMatch: 'full',
            children: [
              {
                path: 'draftArticles', children: [
                  {
                    path: ':articleId',
                    component: DraftArticleComponent,
                    pathMatch: 'full'
                  },
                  {
                    path: '',
                    component: DraftArticlesComponent,
                    pathMatch: 'full'
                  }
                ]
              },
              {
                path: 'articles', children: [
                  {
                    path: '',
                    component: ArticlesComponent,
                    pathMatch: 'full'
                  },
                  {
                    path: ':articleId',
                    component: ArticleComponent,
                    pathMatch: 'full'
                  }
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
```

Above is the structure my routes.

`AuthorNavComponent` is my Sidenav within which I am also using another router-outlet for showing children routes. The button that I am clicking is inside the Sidenav which ultimately calls a method in serviceA which will, after making a call to server, redirect to the above specified URL i.e. https://localhost:4200/author/journals/:journal_Id/draftArticles/:articleId

Please let me know if any more information is required

**Update**

I tried using service in the middle named `journalService` and created a `BehaviorSubject<any[]>` to pass in the route of to navigate to. In the component whose route is `author/journals/3`, I subscribed to this `BehaviorSubject<any[]>` and navigated upon changing the value of this BehaviorSubject passing along relative ActivatedRoute as follows:

**Journal Component**

```
this.js.navigateAgain.subscribe(data => {
      if (data) {
        this.router.navigate(data, {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
      }
    });
```

**Other Component** From where I am changing the value of `BehaviorSubject<any[]>`

```
this.js.navigateAgain.next(['draftArticles', articleId]);
```

**Update 2**
Route could also be generated using this -> `this.router.navigate(['author/journals', journalId, 'draftArticles', articleId]);` but still the below error persists :(

Above technique generated the URL perfectly. But I still get the following error:

[image: Error]

It seems like, there is something wrong with the routing described far above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to the above question is partially mentioned within the question at:

> Update 2 Route could also be generated using this -> this.router.navigate(['author/journals', journalId, 'draftArticles', articleId]); but still the below error persists

Using this, we can pass two parameters. However, I used `router-outlet` for displaying child component. Such that, parent is shown in the main router-outlet while the children are shown in the subsequent router-outlets mentioned within the HTML templates of parent. The routing hierarchy defined above is like: author (parent) then journals/:journal_Id (child to author, parent to onward children) then draftArticles/:articleId (child to journals/:journal_Id) which will be shown in its parent for which I had to mention router-outlet tag in journals/:journal_Id component.

Also, I learned that `pathMatch: 'full'` should not be mentioned in children routes. Now that parent component will also be showing along with the child component, I could simply if-else statement.